# How to construct an iterative number list from boolean config flags in makefile?

Tags: gnu, buildroot, build-system, kbuild

How can I construct an iterative number list from boolean config flags in makefile?

Defined in Config.in

```
config CONFIG_VAR_1
  bool "var 1"
  default y

config CONFIG_VAR_2
  bool "var 2"
  default y
```

Makefile

```
VAR = \
    $(if $(CONFIG_VAR_1), 0) \
    $(if $(CONFIG_VAR_2), 1)

$(foreach i, $(VAR), $(info AVR=$i))
```

Expected result

```
VAR=0
VAR=1
```

With displayed approach I get variable VAR to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

This approach actually works as intended. The variable VAR was empty, because .config was cashed with old values.To make it work I only had to do a `make defconfig && make`